# my website is responsive in chrome extension but when i check it in my phone it's not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsive-design

I have developed I website for one of my clients when I check it by "Mobile/ Responsive Web Design Tester " chrome Extention it's pretty responsive but when I'm checking on my phone it's not responsive I have tried everything that I knew but couldn't find the problem any help will appreciate it

the site line is [Link](https://www.masihkarimi.com)

Comment: Please add your code to this question _ HTML & CSS _ We need to see the code you've used to make your website responsive _ It's not a good idea to rely on Google extensions for your web-dev work _ Chrome Development Tools would be better (F12)

Comment: You didn't code it yourself but you have added code to make it responsive?

Comment: Does the website have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @Masih.karimi You're welcome! I've forgotten that more than I'd like to admit haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 introduced the possibility of controlling the sizing through the `meta` tag. You can use this tag in your `<head>` to tell the device which scale to use on your content.

Try adding this into your page `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: At the time of posting my answer, the page link seems to be serving a Godaddy template page instead of the content in question.